# I need to mock Date using mockito, when i'm trying to mock i'm getting nullpointer exception

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, powermockito

public class EventMapper implements RowMapper {

```
@Override
public EventData mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
    EventData eventData = new EventData();
    eventData.setResourceId(rs.getLong(RESOURCEID));
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
    eventData.setrecordDate(df.format(rs.getDate(RECORDDATE)));
    return eventData;
```

}

### Below is my test class

```
@Test
public void mapRowTest() throws SQLException {
  ResultSet resultSet = mock(ResultSet.class);
  Mockito.when(resultSet.getLong(RESOURCEID)).thenReturn(12345L);
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("2017-08-19 12:20:55");
  Mockito.when((df.format(resultSet.getDate(RECORDDATE)))).thenReturn("2017-08-19 
  12:20:55");
```

eventMapper.mapRow(resultSet, 1);
}

Comment: Add stacktrace. Where exacly in code exception occurs?

Comment: you need to mock rs.getDate(RECORDDATE) - when(resultSet.getDate(RECORDDATE)).thenReturn(...)

Comment: I did that , when i mock like that I'm getting illegal argumentexception